# Divide a sequence into continuous sets of size at most K

Tags: algorithm

Divide a sequence of N numbers into continuous sets of size at-most K such that no two set are neighbour of each other(i.e., there is at least one number in between the two sets) and the sum of all the elements in all the sets gets maximised.

e.g., if sequence is 1,2,3,4,5. We can divide it into sets (1,2) and (4,5) as 3 is in between them but not into sets (2,3) and (4,5).

I have done this O(NK).
Please suggest a better algorithm.

I have already used dynamic programming with back tracing.
My code is :

```
#include<cstdio>
using namespace std;

long long int max(long long int a,long long int b){
     if(a>b) return a;
     else return b;
}

int main(){
    int n,k;
    int p[100000];
    long long int v[100001];
    scanf("%d %d",&n,&k);
    int i,j;
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
        scanf("%d",&p[i]);  
    v[0]=0;
    v[1]=p[n-1];
    int l=1;
    for(i=n-2;i>-1;i--){
        long long int temp=v[l];
        l=(n-i)>k?k:(n-i);
        int m=(k-i)>1?(k-i):1;
        for(j=l;j>=m;j--)
            v[j]=max(p[i]+v[j-1],temp);
        v[0]=temp;
    }
    printf("%lld\n",v[k]);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This kinda smells like homework...

Comment: This is not a homework but just self-practice...

Answer (score 0):

Since it sounds like homework, I will just give you a clue. Use dynamic programming with function: F(x,i,k) where x is the sequence, you are considering first i elements, and k is the number of disjoint sub-sequences.